# I have two lists that are the same, yet I get a FALSE when i try to show they are equivalent

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, broken-code

[image: image of the code]
I have tried changing the variables, reevaluating the cells, but it just keeps giving me false. The weird part is that it was originally true and it changed to false, randomly.I did not want to post the whole thing because I am solving an 18 by 18 matrix. I am using equivalent to prove that the solutions are the same.

```
A={{-581.5, -744.9, 338.2, 342., 200.9, -8.9, 697.2, -339.2, 
128.7, -736.5, 286.6, 464.6, -811.7, -399.5, 977.4, 21.9, 
3.4, -500.6}, {-226.9, -16.7, 496.3, 759.7, -257.4, 514.7, -995.9, 
630.2, -346.4, -653.8, -258.6, -697., 268.6, -69.7, 
486.4, -820., -14.8, -950.5}, {-611.2, -167.8, -749.1, -158.5, \
-513.5, 878.6, 938.3, -782.4, -100.9, 657., -430., -825.1, -956.3, 
491.4, 250.9, -501.4, -596., 75.3}, {462.4, 945.4, -771.5, 
606.9, -80.4, 582.8, 209.7, 613.3, -27.9, 352.3, 19.4, 476.2, 983., 
872.8, 246.6, -313.2, -715.7, 459.7}, {-686., 51.6, 364.7, 
626.4, -876.4, 938.9, -984.2, 36.1, 610., 331.7, -459.6, 961.7, 
847., -303.5, 272., 234.3, -32.2, -147.1}, {134.9, -637.7, 542.6, 
321.5, -852.9, -484.6, 571.9, -536.6, 709.8, 520.1, 919.9, -518.4, 
268.9, -326.1, -177.2, -643.4, 781.9, 971.5}, {376.9, 480.9, 
489.9, -281.5, 921., 724., -252.5, -890.4, -632.5, 754.2, -211.7, 
349.3, 62.9, 772.3, 15.7, 399.1, -415.3, -299.9}, {-570.6, -348.1, 
248.4, -215.1, -749.5, 562.4, -441.2, -795.8, 414., -872.2, 957.4, 
445.3, -533., 636.9, -759.6, 587.4, -567.9, -545.}, {-332.6, -374.9,
695.9, 704., -878.3, 264.1, 518.6, -626.2, -706.9, 154.8, 
835., -725.6, 414.8, 101.1, 642.9, 855., 
159.1, -807.5}, {585., -36.2, -932.6, -995.6, 430.5, -378.4, 
62.6, -662.3, 129.1, 373.8, 807.2, 749.1, -561.3, 855.8, -258.7, 
649.8, -404.4, 271.1}, {-297.8, 635.7, 585.2, 106.3, 806.6, 740., 
827.3, 649.6, 409.6, 532.4, -510., -74.3, 641.7, 318.8, 
490.1, -582.1, -63.7, 977.1}, {175.8, 844.7, 387.8, 753.9, -681.1, 
835.6, 215.3, -117.9, -32.7, 383.6, 
541.8, -971.8, -970.6, -719.9, -667., -141.2, -131.1, 
108.4}, {-288.7, -144.7, -368.7, 666.1, 578., -270., -316.9, 273.5, 
322.3, -987.8, 916.1, 332.4, -106.4, 311.2, -557.2, 352.1, 171., 
677.8}, {-608.4, -336., 428., 4.2, 992.2, 
243.6, -103.1, -585.2, -975.7, -853.5, 687.9, 443.1, -1.9, -788.2, 
910.9, 292.3, 760.5, -508.3}, {740.7, -752.2, -149.7, 127.2, 
93.7, -957.2, -27.4, -54.4, 934.1, 786.7, -367.6, 
254.1, -57.7, -186.9, 276.9, -903.6, 370.4, -443.6}, {592.2, -266.1,
280.9, 307.6, 393.4, 373.1, 982.4, -794.8, -515.1, 
752.2, -104.7, -568.4, 352.4, 710.1, -327.4, -248.7, -977.8, 
583.2}, {-201.5, 527.2, 766.5, -323.4, 
790.7, -468.4, -201.7, -748.5, -145.5, -650.8, -227.2, 
29.7, -854.2, -778.6, -154.3, -220.9, -153.2, -337.}, {-455.4, \
-933.3, 63.4, 961.9, 401.3, 823.3, 538.6, 789.7, 662.7, 116.1, -67.5, 
280.5, 954., 579., -551.6, -58.3, 44.5, -511.8}}

B={-377.3, 661.8, -352.3, -273., 851.5, -724.9, 204., -85., 162.1, 
322.2, -657.9, 100.9, 946.7, 881.4, 393.7, 285.2, 902.6, 604.7}

(*module*)
cramers[A_, b_] := Module[{d = Det[A], a}, 
Table[a = A;[[All, k]] = b; Det[a]/d, {k, Length[A]}]]
R51= cramers[A,B]
```

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `Max[Abs[ B - A.R51 ]]`?

Comment: We would need the actual inputs to be able to figure out where the issue is.  Do you have the original code you could upload?

Comment: A rule of thumb in programming is that you should not compare directly whether two floating point numbers are equal. An easy generalisation of this principle is that you should not compare whether two lists of floating point numbers are equal. Look at the differences of the corresponding slots and see whether they are smaller than a chosen `epsilon`.

Comment: Or test whether `Norm[A.R51 - B]` is less than some `epsilon`

Comment: @kickert i didnt want to put the whole thing because it is long, but i just posted it

Comment: @Shredderroy the thing is i did it for four other answers that also have floating points and it does say that they are equivalent. It is just this one that is annoying me

Comment: @MarisolRoman, I ended up with multiple errors when trying to run the code you included.

Comment: @MarisolRoman, you can use something like the following to isolate where the issue is: `B[[#]] ==A.R51[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[B]]`

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. -- That said, with the actual code posted I don't get `False`, because you left something out.

Comment: You are implementing a linear solver in code. Take a look at MMA,s LinearSolve[ ] command, options, methods, and you’ll see they don’t get exact equality either for any of the methods involving floats. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html

Answer (score 1):

First, the linear algebra method you want to implement is the `LinearSolve` function, you can obtain `r51` as

```
r51 = LinearSolve[aa, bb];
```

Anyway, you get the same problem

```
bb === aa.r51
False
```

However, this is due to numerical problems, because `Max[Abs[bb - aa.r51]]` gives around 10^-13.

You can overcome this problem by setting Rationalized versions of A and b

```
aar = Rationalize[aa];
bbr = Rationalize[bb];
r51r = LinearSolve[aar, bbr];

bbr === aar.r51r
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference B - A.R51 shows all values on the order of 10^-12. This is pretty much zero for floating point numbers. If you want to get exactly zero, you can rationalize the calculations. First rationalize your cramers function

```
cramers[A_, b_] := Module[{d = Det[A], a}, 
   Table[a = A; a[[All, k]] = b; Rationalize[Det[a]/d], {k, Length[A]}]];
```

Then:

```
aRat = Rationalize[A];
bRat = Rationalize[B];
rRat = Rationalize[cramers[aRat, bRat]];
bRat == aRat.rRat
True
```

and you can verify that bRat - aRat.rRat is a vector of all zeroes.

Comment: Also possible to use `Threshold` to clip the difference instead of pulling out the heavy duty symbolics on `Rationalize`